# Python, RegEx, Replace a certain part of a match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a certain part of a match that a regex found.
The relevant strings have the following format:

```
"<Random text>[Text1;Text2;....;TextN]<Random text>"
```

So basically there can be N Texts seperated by a ";" inside the brackets.
My goal is to change the ";" into a "," (but only for the strings which are in this format) so that I can keep the ";" as a seperator for a CSV file. So the result should be:

```
"<Random text>[Text1,Text2,...,TextN]<Random text>"
```

I can match the relevant strings with something like

```
re.compile(r'\[".*?((;).*?){1,4}"\]')
```

but if I try to use the sub method it replaces the whole string.

I have searched stackoverflow and I am pretty sure that "capture groups" might be the solution but I am not really getting there.
Can anyone help me?

I ONLY want to change the ";" in the ["Text1;...;TextN"]-parts of my text file.

Comment: `["Text1;Text2;....;TextN"]` is a string or a list?

Comment: It is a string!

Comment: Why is str.replace(";", ",") not valid for this?

Comment: Valid format is `"Text1;Text2;...;TextN"`. And not valid format is `"Text1;Text2;...;TextM"`, where `M != N`. These strings should be ignored by replacer, isnt it?

Comment: What are the constraints on `N` ?

Comment: `string = re.sub(r'(?<=\w)*[;](?=\w)*','.',"Text1;Text2;....;TextN")`

Comment: How do you know where `Text1` starts? Most likely this can be done with something similar to @AshwinGeetD'Sa comment.

Comment: Text1, Text2, ... Text N are placeholders. So the string can e.g. look like ["Hello;Bye;This123"]. I know where its starts due to [" and where it ends due to "].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
;(?=(?:(?!\[).)*])
```

Replace each match with a `,`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1uP5ff/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `;` - matches a `;`
- `(?=(?:(?!\[).)*])` - makes sure that the above `;` is followed by a closing `]` somewhere later in the string but before any opening bracket `[`

  - `(?=....)` - positive lookahead
  - `(?:(?!\[).)*` - 0+ occurrences of any character which does not start with `[`
  - `]` - matches a `]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match a `;` before a closing `]` and not matching `[` in between you could use:

```
;(?=[^[]*])
```

- `;` Match literally
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^[]*` Negated character class, match 0+ times any char except `[`
- `]` Match literally
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b0reV5/1)

Note that this will also match if there is no leading `[`

---

If you also want to make sure that there is a leading `[` you could make use of the [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module and use `\G` and `\K` to match a single `;`

```
(?:\[(?=[^[\]]*])|\G(?!^))[^;[\]]*\K;
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h7ZbXu/1) | [Python demo](https://rextester.com/NTMT9769)

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:\[(?=[^[\]]*])|\G(?!^))[^;[\]]*\K;"
test_str = ("[\"Text1;Text2;....;TextN\"];asjkdjksd;ajksdjksad[\"Text1;Text2;....;TextN\"]\n\n"
    ".[\"Text1;Text2\"]...long text...[\"Text1;Text2;Text3\"]....long text...[\"Text1;...;TextN\"]...long text...\n\n"
    "I ONLY want to change the \";\" in the [\"Text1;...;TextN\"]")

result = regex.sub(pattern, ",", test_str)
print (result)
```

Output

```
["Text1,Text2,....,TextN"];asjkdjksd;ajksdjksad["Text1,Text2,....,TextN"]

.["Text1,Text2"]...long text...["Text1,Text2,Text3"]....long text...["Text1,...,TextN"]...long text...

I ONLY want to change the ";" in the ["Text1,...,TextN"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code sample:

```
import re
x = 'anbhb["Text1;Text2;...;TextN"]nbgbyhuyg["Text1;Text2;...;TextN"][]nhj,kji,'
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == '[' and x[i + 1] == '"':
        while x[i+2] != '"':
            list1 = list(x)
            if x[i] == ';':
                list1[i] = ','
                x = ''.join(list1)

            i = i + 1

print(x)
```

Comment: If I use str.replace(";",",") it will change every ";" in my text-file. I only want to replace the ";" in the parts which have the following format:

["Text1;Text2;Text3;..;TextN"]